# Append text box and button

Tags: javascript

how to create textbox/text field and button

JavaScript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function addItemTodo(){

  var value = document.getElementById('item1').value;
  var value2 = document.getElementById('item2').value;

  var my_table = document.getElementById('todo');
  var rows = my_table.getElementsByTagName("tr").length;
  row = my_table.insertRow(rows);
  cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
  cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
  cell1.innerHTML = value;
  cell2.innerHTML = value2;
}
</script>
```

HTML Code

```
<input type="text" id="item1" placeholder="item1" size="12">
  <input type="text" id="item2" placeholder="item2" size="14">
  <button id="add" onclick="addItemTodo()">Add</button>

<table border="1" style="width:50%" id="todo">
    <tr>
      <th>Input from 'item1'</th>
      <th>Input from 'item2'</th>
      <th>Text Box</th>
      <th>Button</th>  
    </tr>
</table>
```

How to append the text box and button, when clicked the **add** **button**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create your new elements within your Javascript as strings, and then add them to two new cells (`insertCell(2)` and `insertCell(3)`) using `.innerHTML` like so:

```js
function addItemTodo() {
  var value = document.getElementById('item1').value;
  var value2 = document.getElementById('item2').value;

  var my_table = document.getElementById('todo');
  var rows = my_table.getElementsByTagName("tr").length;
  var row = my_table.insertRow(rows);
  row.insertCell(0).innerHTML = value;
  row.insertCell(1).innerHTML = value2;
  row.insertCell(2).innerHTML = "<input type='text' placeholder='xxx' class='text-box' />";
  row.insertCell(3).innerHTML = "<button>Text</button>";
  
}
```

```css
.text-box {
  width: 50px;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="item1" placeholder="item1" size="12">
<input type="text" id="item2" placeholder="item2" size="14">
<button id="add" onclick="addItemTodo()">Add</button>

<table border="1" style="width:50%" id="todo">
  <tr>
    <th>Input from 'item1'</th>
    <th>Input from 'item2'</th>
    <th>Text Box</th>
    <th>Button</th>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: `<input type='text' class'text-box' />` if i want to design the text box..how to made it?

Comment: @KhengYung you can apply CSS to the `text-box` class. I've updated my answer to provide CSS which changes the width of the textbox

Comment: `row.insertCell(2).innerHTML = "<input type='text' class='text-box' />";` how to put placeholder?

Comment: @KhengYung you can add it directly to the string HTML element: `<input type='text' placeholder='xxx' class='text-box' />`